# create MembershipUser in different Db then is in web.config

Tags: c#

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(UsernameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text);
```

In web.config i have connection string but i would like to use MemBershipUser on different connection string. Is that possible, and if yes how?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution if someone else has similar problem:

A simpler, albeit somewhat eyebrow-raising solution is just modifying the connection 
string in the providers early enough in the request's lifecycle:

```
      private void SetProviderConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        // Set private property of Membership, Role and Profile providers.
        var connectionStringField = Membership.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (connectionStringField != null)
            connectionStringField.SetValue(Membership.Provider, connectionString);

        var roleField = Roles.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (roleField != null)
            roleField.SetValue(Roles.Provider, connectionString);

        var profileField = ProfileManager.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (profileField != null)
            profileField.SetValue(ProfileManager.Provider, connectionString);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an extra connectionstring and use that in your membership configuration. Look at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx
As you can see, the `membership` section references its connection string by name.

Comment: hmm tx for your answer. What about to progamatically add connection strinc in C# code?